# ¿Cómo se hacen las Funciones de Senos, Cosenos y Tangentes Sin Recurrir a las Funciones Matematicas de VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

¿Cómo se hace la función de **Senos**, **Cosenos** y **Tangentes**, con operaciones de suma, resta, multiplicación, división y Raíz Cuadrada?

Lo que necesito es hallar el modo de hacer **Senos**, **Cosenos** y **Tangente**, con solo operaciones de suma, resta, multiplicación, división y raíz cuadrada.

```
If IsMayor(Angulo, "90") = True Then Exit Function
        If PolCalculator.IsMayor(Angulo, "0") = True Then
            If PolCalculator.IsMayor(Angulo, "30") = True Then
                If PolCalculator.IsMayor(Angulo, "45") = True Then
                    If PolCalculator.IsMayor(Angulo, "60") = True Then
                        Dim Temporal As String = BigNumbers.Divide(BigNumbers.Divide(BigNumbers.Raiz(StringTres, Reiterations), StringDos, Reiterations), "60", Reiterations)
                        Return BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Temporal, Angulo)
                    Else
                        Dim Temporal As String = BigNumbers.Divide(BigNumbers.Divide(BigNumbers.Raiz(StringDos, Reiterations), StringDos, Reiterations), "45", Reiterations)
                        Return BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Temporal, Angulo)
                    End If
                Else
                    Dim Temporal As String = BigNumbers.Divide(BigNumbers.Divide(StringUno, StringDos, Reiterations), "30", Reiterations)
                    Return BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Temporal, Angulo)
                End If
            Else
                Dim Temporal As String = BigNumbers.Divide(BigNumbers.Divide(StringUno, StringDos, Reiterations), "30", Reiterations)
                Return BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Temporal, Angulo)
            End If
        Else
            Return StringCero
        End If
```

Comment: Me parece interesante el problema. He buscado x la Wikipedia y he encontrado esto:https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_de_Euler. Mira la parte de la serie de tailor, ahí tienes una posible fórmula.

Comment: Para poder calcularlos, necesitas saber las medidas de los lados del triángulo, como poco. Si no, es complicado.

Comment: Necesito que sea desde el angulo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahora se, que se trata de resolver-lo con la teoría de Pitágoras con los lados del triangulo rectángulo en el que A al cuadrado, más B al cuadrado, son C al Cuadrado con lo que se finaliza haciendo la raíz cuadrada de C.

Para hacer Senos y Cosenos, se hace algo igual pero a 90º hacía la derecha el uno del otro...

Con este método se resuelve el Seno:

```
  Public Function Sin(ByVal Angulo As String, Optional ByVal Reiterations As Integer = 32, Optional ByVal MaxLengthDecimals As Integer = 0) As String
    Sin = StringCero

    On Error Resume Next
    If Reiterations <= 32 Then Reiterations = 32
    If MaxLengthDecimals <= 8 Then MaxLengthDecimals = 8
    If MaxLengthDecimals >= Reiterations Then Reiterations = 32 : MaxLengthDecimals = 8

    Dim Numero1 As String = "10"
    Dim Numero2 As String = "10"
    Dim Numero3 As String = StringCero
    Dim ElevacionA As String = "100"
    Dim ElevacionB As String = "100"
    Dim ElevacionC As String = "200"
    Numero3 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionC, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)

    ' Caso 45
    If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(Angulo, StringCuatro & StringCinco) = True Then
        Dim RaizCuadradaElevaciones As String = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionC, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        Return BigNumbers.Divide(Numero1, RaizCuadradaElevaciones, Reiterations + Ocho)
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Casos de 0 a 44
    If BigNumbers.IsMayor(Angulo, StringCero) = True And BigNumbers.IsMayor(StringCuatro & StringCinco, Angulo) = True Then
        Dim RestoAngulo As String = BigNumbers.Divide(Numero3, "22,5", 32)
        Dim NuevoAngulo As String = BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Angulo, RestoAngulo)
        ElevacionB = BigNumbers.ElevarPotencia(NuevoAngulo, StringDos, 48, 8)
        Numero2 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionB, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        ElevacionC = BigNumbers.Sumar(ElevacionA, ElevacionB)
        Numero3 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionC, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        Return BigNumbers.Restar(StringUno, BigNumbers.Divide(Numero1, Numero3, Reiterations))
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Caso 90
    If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(Angulo, StringNueve & StringCero) = True Then
        Return StringUno
    End If

    ' Casos de 46 a 89
    If BigNumbers.IsMayor(Angulo, StringCuatro & StringCinco) = True And BigNumbers.IsMayor(StringNueve & StringCero, Angulo) = True Then
        Dim RestoAngulo As String = BigNumbers.Divide(Numero3, "11,25", 32)
        Dim NuevoAngulo As String = BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Angulo, RestoAngulo)
        ElevacionB = BigNumbers.ElevarPotencia(NuevoAngulo, StringDos, 48, 8)
        Numero2 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionB, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        ElevacionC = BigNumbers.Sumar(ElevacionA, ElevacionB)
        Numero3 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionC, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        Return BigNumbers.Restar(StringUno, BigNumbers.Divide(Numero1, Numero3, Reiterations + Ocho))
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Caso 135
    If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(Angulo, StringUno & StringTres & StringCinco) = True Then
        Dim RaizCuadradaElevaciones As String = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionC, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        Return BigNumbers.Divide(Numero1, RaizCuadradaElevaciones, Reiterations)
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Casos de 91 a 134
    If BigNumbers.IsMayor(Angulo, "90") = True And BigNumbers.IsMayor("135", Angulo) = True Then
        Dim RestoAngulo As String = BigNumbers.Divide(Numero3, "11,25", 32)
        Angulo = BigNumbers.Restar(Angulo, "135")
        Angulo = BigNumbers.Restar("45", Angulo)
        Dim NuevoAngulo As String = BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Angulo, RestoAngulo)
        ElevacionB = BigNumbers.ElevarPotencia(NuevoAngulo, StringDos, 48, 8)
        Numero2 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionB, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        ElevacionC = BigNumbers.Sumar(ElevacionA, ElevacionB)
        Numero3 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionC, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        Return BigNumbers.Restar(StringUno, BigNumbers.Divide(Numero1, Numero3, Reiterations + Ocho))
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Caso 180
    If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(Angulo, "180") = True Then
        Return StringCero
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Casos de 136 a 179
    If BigNumbers.IsMayor(Angulo, "135") = True And BigNumbers.IsMayor("180", Angulo) = True Then
        Dim RestoAngulo As String = BigNumbers.Divide(Numero3, "22,5", 32)
        Angulo = BigNumbers.Restar("180", Angulo)
        Dim NuevoAngulo As String = BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Angulo, RestoAngulo)
        ElevacionB = BigNumbers.ElevarPotencia(NuevoAngulo, StringDos, 48, 8)
        Numero2 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionB, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        ElevacionC = BigNumbers.Sumar(ElevacionA, ElevacionB)
        Numero3 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionC, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        Return BigNumbers.Restar(StringUno, BigNumbers.Divide(Numero1, Numero3, Reiterations + Ocho))
        Exit Function
    End If


    ' Casos por encima de 180


    ' Caso 315
    If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(Angulo, "315") = True Then
        Dim RaizCuadradaElevaciones As String = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionC, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        Return StringGuion & BigNumbers.Divide(Numero1, RaizCuadradaElevaciones, Reiterations + Ocho)
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Casos de 316 a 359
    If BigNumbers.IsMayor(Angulo, "315") = True And BigNumbers.IsMayor("360", Angulo) = True Then
        Dim RestoAngulo As String = BigNumbers.Divide(Numero3, "22,5", 32)
        Angulo = BigNumbers.Restar("360", Angulo)
        'Angulo = BigNumbers.Restar("45", Angulo)
        Dim NuevoAngulo As String = BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Angulo, RestoAngulo)
        ElevacionB = BigNumbers.ElevarPotencia(NuevoAngulo, StringDos, 48, 8)
        Numero2 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionB, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        ElevacionC = BigNumbers.Sumar(ElevacionA, ElevacionB)
        Numero3 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionC, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        Return StringGuion & BigNumbers.Restar(StringUno, BigNumbers.Divide(Numero1, Numero3, Reiterations + Ocho))
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Caso 270
    If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(Angulo, "270") = True Then
        Return StringGuion & StringUno ' BigNumbers.Divide(Numero1, RaizCuadradaElevaciones, Reiterations)
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Casos de 271 a 315
    If BigNumbers.IsMayor(Angulo, "270") = True And BigNumbers.IsMayor("315", Angulo) = True Then
        Dim RestoAngulo As String = BigNumbers.Divide(Numero3, "11,25", 32)
        Angulo = BigNumbers.Restar(Angulo, "315")
        Angulo = BigNumbers.Restar("45", Angulo)
        Dim NuevoAngulo As String = BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Angulo, RestoAngulo)
        ElevacionB = BigNumbers.ElevarPotencia(NuevoAngulo, StringDos, 48, 8)
        Numero2 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionB, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        ElevacionC = BigNumbers.Sumar(ElevacionA, ElevacionB)
        Numero3 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionC, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        Return StringGuion & BigNumbers.Restar(StringUno, BigNumbers.Divide(Numero1, Numero3, Reiterations + Ocho))
        Exit Function
    End If


    ' Caso 225
    If BigNumbers.IsEqualNumber(Angulo, "225") = True Then
        Dim RaizCuadradaElevaciones As String = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionC, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        Return StringGuion & BigNumbers.Divide(Numero1, RaizCuadradaElevaciones, Reiterations)
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Casos de 226 a 269
    If BigNumbers.IsMayor(Angulo, "225") = True And BigNumbers.IsMayor("270", Angulo) = True Then
        Dim RestoAngulo As String = BigNumbers.Divide(Numero3, "11,25", 32)
        Angulo = BigNumbers.Restar("270", Angulo)
        Angulo = BigNumbers.Restar("90", Angulo)
        Dim NuevoAngulo As String = BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Angulo, RestoAngulo)
        ElevacionB = BigNumbers.ElevarPotencia(NuevoAngulo, StringDos, 48, 8)
        Numero2 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionB, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        ElevacionC = BigNumbers.Sumar(ElevacionA, ElevacionB)
        Numero3 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionC, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        Return StringGuion & BigNumbers.Restar(StringUno, BigNumbers.Divide(Numero1, Numero3, Reiterations + Ocho))
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Casos de 136 a 179
    If BigNumbers.IsMayor(Angulo, "180") = True And BigNumbers.IsMayor("225", Angulo) = True Then
        Dim RestoAngulo As String = BigNumbers.Divide(Numero3, "22,5", 32)
        Angulo = BigNumbers.Restar("225", Angulo)
        Angulo = BigNumbers.Restar("45", Angulo)
        Dim NuevoAngulo As String = BigNumbers.Multiplicar(Angulo, RestoAngulo)
        ElevacionB = BigNumbers.ElevarPotencia(NuevoAngulo, StringDos, 48, 8)
        Numero2 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionB, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        ElevacionC = BigNumbers.Sumar(ElevacionA, ElevacionB)
        Numero3 = BigNumbers.RaizY(ElevacionC, StringDos, Reiterations, MaxLengthDecimals)
        Return StringGuion & BigNumbers.Restar(StringUno, BigNumbers.Divide(Numero1, Numero3, Reiterations + Ocho))
        Exit Function
    End If

End Function
```